# Speed of bound lambda (via std::function) vs operator() of functor struct

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, lambda

```
auto lam = [](int a, int b, int c) { return a < b && b < c; };

struct functor {
  int a;
  int b;
  bool operator()(int n) const { return a < n && n < b; }
};
```

In version one, we

```
std::vector<std::function<bool (int)>> lamvals;
// get parameters and for each
lamvals.emplace_back(std::bind(lam, a, std::placeholders::_1, b));
```

The alternative is

```
std::vector<functor> lamvals;
// get parameters and for each
lamvals.emplace_back(functor{a, b});
```

In both cases we have a simple iteration

```
    return std::any_of(lamvals.cbegin(), lamvals.cend(),
            [n](const decltype(lamvals)::value_type & t){return t(n);});
```

I am seeing a speed difference of 3:1, with the bound lambda slower. The functor is almost as fast as storing integer pairs and hardcoding the tests. Obviously, hardcoding is not as useful for the production code, because there will be several functions in play, not just between. However, I can go with either many functors or many lambdas. The latter is fewer lines of code and looks cleaner, but I don't think I can afford that speed difference; this code is in a critical loop.

I am looking for speedup suggestions.

Comment: The use of `std::function` would of course be slower. With it most possibly implemented through type erasure (which boils down to `virtual` and possible dynamic allocation) then it would cause significant overhead compared to a "plain" functor.

Comment: Store your functor in a `std::function` and it will take the same time as the lambda.

Comment: It's very important to note that lambdas are not slower than functors. Instead, `std::function` calls are slower than regular function calls.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference between the two cases is fundamentally that with the functor, the compiler knows exactly what will be called at compile time, so the function call can be inlined. Lambdas, interestingly enough, also have a unique type. This means again, when you use a lambda, at compile type (since the compiler must know all types) the function being called is already known, so inlining can occur. On the other hand, a function pointer is type based only on its signature. The signature must be known so that it can be called to and returned from appropriately, but other than that a function pointer can point to anything at run-time, as far as the compiler is concerned. The same is true about std::function.

When you wrap the lambda in a std::function, you erase the type of the lambda from a compiler perspective. If this sounds weird/impossible, think of it this way: since a std::function of a fixed type can wrap any callable with the same signature, the compiler has no way of knowing that some other instruction won't come alone and change what the std::function is wrapping.

This link, http://goo.gl/60QFjH, shows what I mean (by the way, the godbolt page is very very handy, I suggest getting acquainted with it). I wrote three examples here similar to yours. The first uses std::function wrapping a lambda, the second a functor, the third a naked lambda (unwrapped), using decltype. You can look at the assembly on the right and see that both of the latter two get inlined, but not the first.

My guess is that you can use lambdas to do exactly the same thing. Instead of bind, you can just do value based capture with the lambdas of a and b. Each time you push back the lambda into the vector, modify a and b appropriately, and voila.

Stylistically though, I actually strongly feel you should use the struct. It's much clearer what's going on. The mere fact that you are seeming to want to capture a and b in one place, and test against c in another, means that this is used in your code in not just one place. In exchange for like, 2 extra lines of code, you get something more readable, easier to debug, and more extensible.

Comment: Very helpful. How would you declare the struct, when I want various operator()s all with that signature? Virtual will kill the inlining. Is the compiler going to accept decltype of the output of std::bind?

Comment: Inlining implies zero indirection, but having a container that is capable of storing callables that are actually calling out to different ()'s implies some amount of indirection. These two goals are incompatible, short of the compiler being really smart and looking at your whole program, which you can't count on it to do.
In the case of the struct, you can actually get rid of the virtual issue by using the final keyword. However, your container will have to store points rather than objects, so there is is still a pointer dereference involved that will typically prevent inlining.

Comment: @NirFriedman: They're not 100% incompatable... if you know which will be called at compile time you can use a tuple.  Other than that, yes.

Comment: @Mooing Duck This is a very good point to mention, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Note that compilers can often optimize function pointers like lambdas; it is only a bit less reliable.  `std::function` is in practice harder (I have never seen it fully optimized away).

Comment: @Yakk I tried with a function pointer; it seems like even in this very simple case it is unable to inline: http://goo.gl/R9X2FW. Also, I'm not sure in what context you mean "it is only a bit less reliable". Lambdas can always be inlined, in many cases its actually impossible to inline a function pointer, in many other cases it is very impractical (requiring a large amount of non-local analysis).

Comment: @NirFriedman This simple a case: http://goo.gl/Pp8RcN it appears to work.  Many cases where you can inline a lambda you can do the same with a function pointer.  Sometimes you need a slightly different syntax (like using a template value parameter instead of a function parameter), but not always.  You'll note that the operation you did on the function pointer (store it in a vector) is not something you can do usefully to a non-type erased lambda.  It is less reliable, but you can get function pointer values to be inlined in gcc quite often.  Lambdas, on the other hand, basically never fail.

Comment: @Yakk I'm confused, when I click on the link you put in I just see the same example I sent you. Sure, "many cases" in absolute terms. But the difference in how likely they are to be inlined is not a bit, it's quite huge. std::sort is another classic case, unless the entire sort gets inlined (uncommon) the function pointer is unlikely to be inlined.